# How to add line in html designing interface?

Tags: html, css, laravel, interface

I'm trying to designing my interface. But somehow I produce it produce the wrong output that I want. I can't figured out why it happen like this.

MY INTERFACE:

[image]

The interface that I desired to do:

[image]

`welcome.blade.php`

```
 <div class="w-100 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="w-50">
         <h1 class="display-2 text-white"> Task App </h1>
         <h2 class="text-white pt-5"> Next Task? </h2>
            <form action="{{route('task.store')}}" method="POST">
                @csrf
              <div class="input-group mb-3 w-100">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="title" placeholder="Type here..." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="button-addon2">Add your task</button>
                <div>
              <div>
            </form>
            <h2 class="text-white pt-2"> My Task List:</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Might not be the cleanest way, but have you tried adding <br> after your </form> tag?

Comment: yeah I did but it did not work

Comment: Use `display:block`.

Comment: where should i put that line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your code fragment is your actual code, then you have invalid HTML syntax. Some `<div>` tags are not closed. I fixed that and everything looks correct.

```css
#main-div {
 background: #555;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="w-100 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="main-div">
  <div class="w-50">
    <h1 class="display-2 text-white"> Task App </h1>
    <h2 class="text-white pt-5"> Next Task? </h2>
    
    <form action="{{ route('task.store') }}" method="POST">
      <div class="input-group mb-3 w-100">
        <input type="text"
               class="form-control form-control-lg">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-success" 
                  type="submit">
            Add your task
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <h2 class="text-white pt-2"> My Task List:</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe that I missed the enclosing tag!